# How to convert an existing field from Text to Link in Drupal 7

Tags: entities

If I have a field in Drupal which of type Text, how do I convert it to to allow a link if the field is already being used on the site without losing data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Install the [Link](http://drupal.org/project/link) module in order to allow link fields.
2. In your database, run:

   `UPDATE field_config set type='link_field', module='link' WHERE field_name='YOUR_FIELD_ID'`
3. Then run the following query:

   `UPDATE field_config_instance SET data='a:7:{s:5:"label";s:LENGTH_OF_YOUR_FIELD_NAME:"YOUR_FIELD_NAME";s:6:"widget";a:5:{s:6:"weight";s:1:"9";s:4:"type";s:10:"link_field";s:6:"module";s:4:"link";s:6:"active";i:0;s:8:"settings";a:0:{}}s:8:"settings";a:10:{s:12:"validate_url";i:1;s:3:"url";i:0;s:5:"title";s:8:"optional";s:11:"title_value";s:0:"";s:15:"title_maxlength";s:3:"128";s:13:"enable_tokens";i:1;s:7:"display";a:1:{s:10:"url_cutoff";s:2:"80";}s:10:"attributes";a:5:{s:6:"target";s:6:"_blank";s:3:"rel";s:0:"";s:5:"class";s:0:"";s:18:"configurable_title";i:0;s:5:"title";s:0:"";}s:10:"rel_remove";s:7:"default";s:18:"user_register_form";b:0;}s:7:"display";a:1:{s:7:"default";a:5:{s:5:"label";s:5:"above";s:4:"type";s:12:"link_default";s:8:"settings";a:0:{}s:6:"module";s:4:"link";s:6:"weight";i:16;}}s:8:"required";i:0;s:11:"description";s:0:"";s:13:"default_value";N;}' WHERE field_name='YOUR_FIELD_ID'`
4. (optional) Go into the table for your field name (field_data_field_YOUR_FIELD_NAME) and remove the column field_YOUR_FIELD_NAME_format
5. In the same table as #4 above, change the column field_YOUR_FIELD_NAME_value to field_YOUR_FIELD_NAME_title. This will make the previous values for these text fields now become the title of any links placed in the new Link field.
6. In the same table as #4 above, add the columns `field_YOUR_FIELD_NAME_url VARCHAR(2048) ALLOW NULL`, and `field_YOUR_FIELD_NAME_attributes MEDIUMTEXT ALLOW NULL`

This solution worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dynamic Views solution which i believe can do the job quickly for present and new text fields:

You can attach an [EVA](http://www.drupal.org/project/eva) field views display to the nodes of the content type containing that field. In this views display you'll add the text field and then output it as a link within the replacement patterns option. After that i recommend to use [Display Suite](http://www.drupal.org/project/ds) (although not mandatory-you can do most of this out of the box also) to put this field anywhere in the node layout and hide the original text field.

Comment: https links to drupal.org give 403 Forbidden. Please edit them to http links that works for everyone. I can't do this, 'cause it's 2 characters long edit and minimum is 6 characters.

Answer (score 0):

While I subscribe to the first answer, I also want to add an alternative. Create a template for your field, and pass the output though [l()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) function which formats an internal or external URL link as an HTML anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'word link' module in Drupal to convert text to link while editing articles. 
This page has more info on this module - http://www.drupalasisee.com/word-link

Answer (score -1):

https://drupal.org/project/node_convert‎ is another option - create a new template, add an action and use views bulk operation to convert them all..